# postgres transpose table column names are dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I have the following problem

I need to transpose table where i column names are dates (range can vary, so it can be 5 columns or 31 depends on user's selection)

so table like

```
rw_date   | rw_worker   | rw_shift
2010-10-10| Johy        | 07-10
2010-10-10| Ana         | 07-10
2010-10-10| Miley       | 12-16
2010-10-11| Johy        | 07-10
2010-10-11| Ana         | 12-14
2010-10-11| Miley       | 16-20
```

........
becomes

```
rw_worker | 2010-10-10   | 2010-10-11 |.....
Johny     |  07-10       | 07-10      |.....
Ana       |  07-10       | 12-14      |.....
Miley     |  12-16       | 16-20      |.....
```

Thank you

Best regards

Comment: This is something that is usually done client-side, not server-side.